# Error when checking input with keras model

Tags: keras, model, python-3.6

I'am train model, save model on disk, and I get error while use model.

```
Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (150, 150, 3)
```

Train model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3))
```

Use model:

```
model = load_model(os.path.join('models', 'myModel.h5'))
model.predict(img) # img - OpenCV image
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import numpy as np
model.predict(img[np.newaxis, :, :, :])
```